# Issue in While Loop sending email for many users

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to when I click in my sendForm button, I want to send an email for all of my active users.

I have this code below, and I have a While loop to send an email for every emails that I have in my condition (status = active) .

But the email is only sending for my first email in the table and not for every mail that I have.

Somebody there see why this is happening?

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
{
    $verifyUser= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = ?");  
    $verifyUser->bindValue(1, 'active');
    $verifyUser->execute();
    $verifyUserRows= $verifyUser->rowCount();

    if($verifyUserRows<= '0')
    {
    echo 'there are no active warnings'; 
    }

  else
  {
    while ($verifyUserResult= $verifyUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
    $date = date('d/m/Y H:i');
    $msg = " 

    Hi, this is my message!

    Send at $data
    ";

    sendMail('My subject',$msg,MAILUSER,$verifyUserResult['email']);
    echo 'Email sent with sucess'; 
    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return` will exit the loop

Comment: Maybe you meant to put the `return` outside the while statement.

Comment: @Ibu the `return` is inside the `while`, and should not be there at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your return; statement is within your while loop.

The return statement in this particular loop will cause the loop to terminate. In this case, you have placed it as the last statement of the loop and so it will process your first email to send out, then terminate.

To fix the problem, remove the return; statement completely.

Comment: Omg..Im slow today! I put the echo outside while and it works just fine! Thank you!

Comment: With the code you entered, return; does not actually show the error or success message as it is not returning any value at all. Your echo statement will still work in the while loop. In fact, if sendMail returns a value to indicate a successfully sent mail, you can add a condition to check on that return value and echo out the appropriate statement, all inside the while loop.

Comment: Yes, but I put the echo outside the while loop, because if it is inside it will repeat the message as many time as my send emails!